# Compute Engine Spec info missing in GCP Billing API's response

Tags: rest, api, google-cloud-platform

I am struggling to find Compute Engine (CPU, Memory) information in billing API results! All I am getting in response is (just one JSON stanza):

```
{
      "name": "services/6F81-5844-456A/skus/97B8-17A7-16B1",
      "skuId": "97B8-17A7-16B1",
      "description": "Licensing Fee for Secured Mautic on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on f1-micro",
      "category": {
        "serviceDisplayName": "Compute Engine",
        "resourceFamily": "License",
        "resourceGroup": "Cxxxxys",
        "usageType": "OnDemand"
      },
      "serviceRegions": [
        "global"
      ],
      "pricingInfo": [
        {
          "summary": "",
          "pricingExpression": {
            "usageUnit": "h",
            "usageUnitDescription": "hour",
            "baseUnit": "s",
            "baseUnitDescription": "second",
            "baseUnitConversionFactor": 3600,
            "displayQuantity": 1,
            "tieredRates": [
              {
                "startUsageAmount": 0,
                "unitPrice": {
                  "currencyCode": "USD",
                  "units": "0",
                  "nanos": 100000000
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "currencyConversionRate": 1,
          "effectiveTime": "2019-01-04T01:08:22.878Z"
        }
      ],
      "serviceProviderName": "Cxxxxys"
    }
```

I understand, I can be questioned to look and parse the description tab but it doesn't stick to proper format - its a mix of VM's category (f1-micro) or CPU.
Which doesn't serve the purpose.

I have tried to use filter but that would only tailor information presented above.

Tried searching for a common attribute between above output and response from Compute Engine's MachineType API but no luck still.

Hoping if someone can help me with ideas on how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You first need to grab the service id (Looks like a guid) from the Services/ api call.

There is a field is called "Product" in the billing export. Compare this against the "DisplayName" from the API call. This will give you the service ID.

Then use that service Id in the subsequent SKUs call.

You can match the "Resource Type" Field from your billing export to the "Description" field in the api response. They should match up 1:1.

You will get SKUs like "N1 Predefined Instance Ram running in Frankfurt"

- https://cloud.google.com/billing/v1/how-tos/catalog-api
- https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery